# Why simulating Control_A with Robot in Java is not working?

Tags: java, awt, keypress, awtrobot

I use the following lines to simulate a Control_A [ select all ] key action in Java with robot, but the clipboard is not getting the text, why ?

```
        Robot robot=null;
        try { robot=new Robot(); }
        catch (AWTException ex) { System.err.println("Can't start Robot: " + ex); }
        robot.mouseMove(260,500);
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
//        robot.mouseMove(660,700);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);              // Select all
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);              // Copy
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

        Transferable t=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);
        try
        {
          if (t!=null && t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor))
          {
            String text=(String)t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            System.out.println(text);
          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

I have a browser open so at [260,500] on screen there is text at that area. What have I missed ?

Edit:

I just found something strange, when I opened a browser, the text in the browser is not copies, but if I open a notepad/wordpad, the text in them will be copies, so why the browser didn't do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. All of your code should be inside the `try` block where you instantiate the `Robot` because you could end up trying to work with a null reference and get a `NullPointerException`. And if your `Robot` never got created and never copied contents, there'd be no point in you trying to access the contents from the clipboard either.
2. I'm not entirely sure why but adding a small delay before trying to read from the clipboard fixes things. I'm guessing it might have to do with a race condition between Java getting hold of the clipboard *before* the system has had time to update it.

This updated code should work:

```
Robot robot = null;
try
{
    robot = new Robot();
    robot.mouseMove(260, 500);
    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    // robot.mouseMove(660,700);
    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); // Select all
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL); // Copy
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

    try
    {
        //sleep just a little to let the clipboard contents get updated
        Thread.sleep(25);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);
    try
    {
        if (t != null && t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor))
        {
            String text = (String) t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
catch (AWTException ex)
{
    System.err.println("Can't start Robot: " + ex);
}
```

Comment: I just tried, and I increased the sleep time to 2 seconds, but still not working, the contents/text from browser is still not copied ? Have you tried it ? What's missing ? New finding, see "My Edit". Works in wordpad/notepad, but NOT in browser, why ?

Comment: @Frank Yes, I did try it and it worked with both Notepad++ and Firefox 4. What OS/JRE/browser? Try removing the section that deals with the clipboard, only run the code that invokes CTRL+A and CTRL+C. Then, try to paste the copied text and see if that works. That's what I did to figure out what was happening with your original code.

Comment: I use Firefox 3.6.15, which didn't work, but I tried it on IE9, it works fine, so only Firxfox is having problem, could it because I have surfed some sites that have disabled my browser copying of text, so now it's locked up ? If so how to unlock it ?

Comment: Are you saying that you're trying to copy text from a page that doesn't allow you to? I don't think that's really possible without either disabling JavaScript, [using a trick like this](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2008/12/01/how-to-select-and-copy-text-from-restricted-website/) or perhaps doing something browser specific. Since this somewhat beyond the scope of your original question which seems to have been answered, I'd suggest you post a new question that deals specifically with this issue of copying text from from a page that disables it (usually using JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your code context but I had the same problem trying to extract the text from a PDF document on the browser.
It was misleading because the ctrl-a was highlighting the text but ctlr-c copied nothing. My solution was first to simulate a click anywhere on the document first, then ctrl-a and ctrl-c. My code:

```
        robot = new Robot();
        //Get window size
        Dimension d = driver.manage().window().getSize(); 
        System.out.println("Dimension x and y :"+d.getWidth()+" "+d.getHeight()); 
        int x = (d.getWidth()/4)+20; 
        int y = (d.getHeight()/10)+50; 
        robot.mouseMove(x,y); 

        //Clicks Left mouse button
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK); 
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        Thread.sleep(25);

        // Select all
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        Thread.sleep(100);

        // Copy to clipboard
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        Thread.sleep(100);
```

Hope this helps.